# Is the most efficient way to constantly update a label on screen to simply change the label's text property?

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, settext

Say I have to update a label 1000 times a minute. Completely change its string value. Am I best off making 1000 `setText:` calls per minute? Or is there a more efficient way? Perhaps doing away with labels completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two options - update the `text`property of a `UILabel` or draw an `NSString` directly onto a `UIView` (after first erasing the previous value). You'll have to run some tests to see which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can update some local field/variable and use Timer which read value from variable as frequent as it necessary and update Label. You can also use some throttle strategies.
I'm not an iOS expert so I say what my intuition says to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this github library in one of my projects https://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel, which basically subclasses a UILabel and counts down from some initial value to some final value with a custom duration that you can specify, and it is quite efficient and smooth. You can have a look at their code and it might help.